# Merge current branch with upstream (or any other ref) in git2go

Tags: go, libgit2

I'm trying to replicate the outcome of the following command in git2go:

```
git merge -X theirs --no-ff -m "Commit msg" <commit>
```

I'm able to successfully fetch the upstream remote using `remote.Fetch(nil, nil, "")`, but I cannot do the actual merge. This is the code I'm using for merging:

```
// get the upstream ref's annotated commit to merge in
head, _ := repo.Head()
upstream, _ := head.Branch().Upstream()
annotatedCommit, _ := repo.AnnotatedCommitFromRef(upstream)

// prepare merge and checkout options
mergeOpts, _ := git.DefaultMergeOptions()
mergeOpts.FileFavor = git.MergeFileFavorTheirs
checkoutOpts := git.CheckoutOpts{
    Strategy: git.CheckoutUseTheirs,
}

// do the merge
err := repo.Merge([]*git.AnnotatedCommit{annotatedCommit}, &mergeOpts, &checkoutOpts)
// no error here
```

I understand that after this I need to check the index for any conflicts, and actually do the commit with the two parents, however I'm stuck here at the moment because the `Merge()` doesn't appear to be doing anything (no merge, no checkout).

Comment: After you call `repo.Merge` how do you know nothing has happened? I just glanced at the code and it seems like you're using it correctly, if no error occurs I would expect something to happen, at least for the changes to be staged.

Comment: The changes are not staged, the index is not updated in any way. The only thing that I can see is the origin/master being updated, as a result of the `Fetch()` and if I `git checkout origin/master` I can see the new changes in the working tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout is performing a dry run by default, so to be able to successfully merge I had to use something like this:

```
checkoutOpts := git.CheckoutOpts{
    Strategy: git.CheckoutSafe | git.CheckoutRecreateMissing | git.CheckoutAllowConflicts | git.CheckoutUseTheirs,
}
```

The only documentation available is in the [checkout.go source](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/blob/next/checkout.go#L16).